# Flutter FCM - Unable to launch app when tapping on Push notification while app is in both background and terminated state

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I currently using FCM push notification to my flutter app with `firebase_messaging` version 13.1.0

I try to launch the app when the user tap on a notification when the app is in background or terminated state but not launching the app

The above scenario is working fine when sending notification using POSTMAN. But not working in production environment. i.e, Actual push notifications are sending from server once payment confirmed.

```
{
    "notification": {
        "title": "Payment Received",
        "body": "You have received 10 Rupees"
    },
    
    "to": "f1OhZ7mZSai2ZLiQSdf_x12QCuxYbCbsxdeweEWEWEDSFDGREWEWP0ihdmkVEWakJBVoGvy2-urd1E0M"
   
}
```

I have specified the below intent filter as well in AndroidManifest.xml,

```
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   </intent-filter>
```